# ionic2 Angular2 import/export JSON data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

What I mean by import/export data and why it needs to be implemented..

1) I want my app to work offline - store data added by user while offline.

2) The data stored in JSON format.

3) I want that JSON data to export in a file and stored in phone memory.

4) Multiple files will be created.

5) When user get internet - the exported file will be imported and that JSON object to be stored in datastore - any server like Firebase.

---

Please suggest how this could be possible in Ionic2, Angular2.

- The JSON object to be export in file - while offline.
- Later that file will be imported and the data to be save over server.

Yet everything is working while online.
Due to large collection of data AngularFire2 like offline library wasn't working properly.

Please suggest possibilities..

Answer (score 0):

Use @ionic/storage.
Its going to use either indexDB, WebDb or SQLite. In any case all these database types store key/values which is essentially json files.

You can:
1) Consider a key as one json file. 
Extract it modify it and insert it back. The speed hits aren't so bad for this.

2) Consider each file as a separate collection. In this case you can store each array element as a key and then modify it.

Note you can also skip using the @ionic/storage and simply use the database apis directly.